# Graph $(r-2)^2+z^2=1$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, cylindrical-coordinates

I was doing a problem and I got stuck at the step of drawing this:

$(r-2)^2+z^2=1$

Since it does not depend on $\theta$, I know it would be like a circle centered at $(2,0)$ with radius $1$ in $xz$ plane, but couldn't imagine how would it be in the space. Any help would be appreciated.

Is there any website that helps me to graph such equations? Thanks

Comment: It's a cylinder

Comment: See [CalcPlot3D](https://tinyurl.com/pf7543s6), it gives a torus.

Comment: @Raffaele Thank you!

Comment: @DMcMor Thanks! That was so helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace $r$ by $x,$ the new equation defines a circle of radius $1$ in the X-Z plane. Now rotate about the Z-axis to get the torus. (You can use this trick whenever there is no $\theta.$)

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!